# Fixed div Width and overflow vertical only with dynamic text

Tags: html, css

I add dynamic text to a tab(jquery ui tab) using a function based on onchange event of a combo box. The script works. The problem is it grows horizontal only. I don't need horizontal growth. Even though I have defined the max width, it doesn't concern it and grow horizontally.

## I need to grow it vertically. that means to start appending to a new line when it reaches to the maximum width limit of the conatiner

```
from jquery UI(you can down load this)

<div id="myTabs"> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#a" id="tabok"><span style="background:#85E085; color:#000;  padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">OK</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#b" id="tabdnt"><span style="background:#FFD6AD; color:#000;  padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">Not Sure</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#c" id="tabdif"><span style="background:#FFB2B2; color:#000;  padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;">Too Difficult</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="a" style="padding-top:0; margin-top:0; max-width:200px;" >
                </div>
        <div id="b"></div>
        <div id="c"></div>
    </div>
    <!--<script src="development-bundle/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>-->
    <script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $("#myTabs").tabs();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

===========================================================

the script i wrote

```
    newlink = document.createElement('a');

newlink.innerHTML = idname;
newlink.setAttribute('title', 'dsdsd');
newlink.setAttribute('href', '#'+idname);
newlink.setAttribute('class', 'k');
    $("#a").append(newlink);
    $(".k").css("padding-left","5px")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the css property white-space: normal in divs that have max-width. This will make the div respect the line breaks.